# Lp space is a Hom functor

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, category-theory, lp-spaces, functors

Is there way to see $L^1$ a functor from the category with objects as metric measure spaces $(X,d,\mu)$ and morphisms Lipschitz maps to the category of Banach spaces (or something which has a forgetful functor to the category of topological vector spaces)?

Comment: You might be interested by [these slides](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~tl/cambridge_ct14/cambridge_ct14_talk.pdf) of Tom Leinster, especially the second part. [This short note](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~tl/glasgowpssl/banach.pdf) is more related to the first part, but might contain a few useful remarks.

Comment: Indeed, I have come across these last evening.  Do you happen to know if there is an acompanying paper?  It seems that there are few citations

Comment: I don't think there is; at least there is no paper on this subject listed on his webpage (where I found the other links). There is an [nCafé post](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2014/07/the_categorical_origins_of_leb.html) though.

Comment: This is interesting.  I'll send him a mail then I guess, thanks Arnaud :)